# Hash doesn't catch if it is nil

Tags: ruby, erb

I am trying to run a .each on an hash.  However, sometimes it is nil.  When I check if it is nil... it says it is not.  Then I get the following exception:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my code.  Any idea why it is not working?

```
if @abc[:def] != nil
  @abc[:def].each do |ghi|     <---- Fails Here
    .
    .
    .
  end
end
```

Any ideas / suggestions would be great.

Update:

@abc is not nil.  If I do a PUTS of abc I receive the following:

```
puts "abc:  #{@abc}"
abc:  {:val1=>"123", :val2=>"234"}
puts "abc[:def]:  #{@abc[:def]}"
abc[:def]:  []
```

@abc is created using YAML.  Here is how it is instantiated.

```
@abc = YAML.load(File.open(pathToYamlFile/yamlFile.yml))
```

Comment: `abc` isn't an array, it's a hash. There's a big difference in how elements are accessed, and methods don't always behave the same. Please show an accurate example of how `abc` is defined. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: `@abc[:def] is nil` will be printed when you run this: `@abc = {:val1=>"123", :val2=>"234"}; if @abc[:def] != nil; @abc[:def].each do |ghi|; puts ghi; end; else; puts "@abc[:def] is nil"; end`? (You can, of course, replace each of my semi-colons with a newline.) Please show how this code is altered to give your result.  Incidentally, I suggest you write `puts "@abc:  #{@abc}" #=> abc:  {:val1=>"123", :val2=>"234"}` so you are not displaying intermixed lines of code and output.

Comment: @theTinMan This should be fixe.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Show us the definition of `@abc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if @abc && @abc[:def]
  @abc[:def].each do |ghi|
    .
    .
    .
  end
end
```

If you're still getting the error, then it is probably occurring within the block, and the error message just locates the line where the block starts.

Comment: @abc is not nil.  I updated my original post to show what it is.

Comment: @CameronJones It's probably an error *within* the `each` block, where you're trying to access `nil[]` and the error message just locates the line where the block starts. Try to find the error in the block, or post the block if you want more eyes on it.

Comment: @abc is not nil.  I showed what it displays in my original post.  However, @abc[:def] is an array... which is why I am doing a .each on it.  This is the value that is nil.

However, when I do the check it does not catch it.  That is what I find odd.

Comment: I have thrown in print statements to find out where it fails.  There is a puts statement as the first thing after the .each and it does display that puts.

Comment: @CameronJones If `:def` is not in a hash, the normal value of `@abc[:def]` should be nil, not the empty array as in your post. `[]` must be overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
if @abc.nil? && @abc[:def].nil?
    # do the other stuffs
end
```

Comment: @abc is not nil.  I updated my original post to show what it is.

Comment: try,
    unless @abc[:def].nil?
       # do
    end

Answer (score 0):

instead of `if @abc[:def] != nil`

use

`if @abc.key?(:def) && !@abc[:def].nil?`

Comment: That may be good advice generally, but I don't see how it answers the question.